# Wordpress HTTP Request 501 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https, internal-server-error

Hello i have digitalocean one click application contains Wordpress.
I add domain to my server and create SSL certificate for my server.
https://example.com works good but when i request
http://example.com its redirect -> http://myserverip.com and gives that error:

---

**Internal Server Error**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

**Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.**

**More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

**Additionally, a 301 Moved Permanently error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

---

Please help me about it. I try to redirect http to https but its not work!
Here it is my .htaccess file contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry still the same :/

Comment: What is your site URL listed under yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-general.php

Comment: Wordpress URL(https) => (https://example.com)   | Site URL(https) =>(https://example.com)